# QT расширение файла

Tags: c++, qt

Как сохранить файл со своим расширением и можно ли сохранить данные в БД, допустим в sqlite с расширением, которое сам придумаю? Использую Qt creater

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Расширение файлов - вещь придуманная весьма условно. Позволяет делать "ассоциации" для запуска определенной программой. Microsoft популяризовала это весьма настойчиво, как единый обязательный стандарт (хотя на самом деле таковым не является).

Вы можете использовать любые имена файлов и их расширения. Просто без указания "программы по-умолчанию" для этого расширения оно не будет открываться нужным приложением (условно по двойному клику).

Судя по вопросу "как?" - qt-creator автоматически добавляет свое расширение после создания файла? Если это так - то нужно либо найти в настройках соответствующий пункт, либо при выборе сохранения есть выпадающй список с расширениями. Если нет возможности сделать ни того, ни другого - переименовать файл после сохранения средствами операционной системы.

Answer (score 0):

Просто задайте имя файла с нужным вам расширением, только и всего. Как и БД может быть в любом файле, с любым расширением. Важно, как вы будете этот файл обрабатывать :)

Кстати, те же sqlite-файлы встречал в реальных программах и как `.sqlite` (Mozilla), как `.db` (Far, Skype, Adobe), `.db3` (Nokia Data Store), и даже вовсе без расширения (Adobe Acrobat) :)